# dart performance for iterables using where

Tags: list, performance, dart

i'm trying to get better performance from a pattern check in a really wide list of strings.

i need the 5 first occurences that would match a given pattern.

i was wondering if

> list.where(pattern in string).take(5)

was lazily computed and stops after 5 occurences found or
does it compute all the where and then takes the 5 first ? ( in that case, is there a whereXfirstOccurences method where X is a number ? )

thank you,

**Edit:**
i did some investigation

> myList.where((element) {bool isSuggestion = the conditions ;
> if (isSuggestion) index++;
> return isSuggestion;
> })
> .take(x)
> .toList();
> print(index);

the index is always at most equal to x so i guess it's lazy evaluation as mentionned below, Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Iterables *are* lazy.

If you do `list.where(computation).take(5)`, it:

- Doesn't do anything at all, until you start iterating.
- It doesn't do anything except when you call `moveNext` on the iterator.
- And it stops doing anything once `moveNext` has returned false, which it does after five elements here, because of the `take(5)`.

If you just use `for (var v in list.where(...).take(5)) ...` you won't see those steps, but they are still there. The loop stops after finding five values, and no further elements are looked at than the ones needed to find the first five satisfying the `where` condition.

That might still be a lot of strings looked at, if the condition is very picky. If there are only four matching strings in the input, you will go through all of the input when looking for the first five matches.
Optimizing the pattern itself can definitely be valuable as well.